# Reading edges from a file. I can't define a graph

Tags: r, igraph

I am new in R. I am working with igraph library. I am new using such library.

I have a problem:

I have a list of edges in a text file. It has two columns. The first has initial node, the second has the ending node.

I am reading the file with:

```
g1 <-read.table ("g1.txt")
```

The reading is successfull.

with `ls.str(g1)` i get:

```
V1 :  int [1:995] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
V2 :  int [1:995] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
```

when i try to define the graph with the just loaded edges I get:

```
Error in graph(g1) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How i could to define the graph from file's edges avoiding the above error?

Comment: It would help us answer your question if you could provide a small sample of the text file.  If the file is small, you can try using `dput`.  
`ls.str` has as its first argument http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/ls_str.html: pos = -1.  I suspect it's trying to coerce your list into a double to enter into the pos argument.  Unlikely to be what you want!

Comment: Maybe `as.matrix()` on the object works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Sacha Epskamp suggested, `as.matrix` may sort this out, possibly with a transpose.

The following recreates your error message and then produces a graph from the same data

```
> library(igraph)
> g1 <- data.frame( V1 = c(0,0,0,0), V2 = c(2,3,4,5) )
> g1
  V1 V2
1  0  2
2  0  3
3  0  4
4  0  5
>
> graph(g1)
Error in graph(g1) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> 
> g2 <- t(as.matrix(g1))
> g2
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
V1    0    0    0    0
V2    2    3    4    5
>
> graph(g2)
Vertices: 6 
Edges: 4 
Directed: TRUE 
Edges:

[0] 0 -> 2
[1] 0 -> 3
[2] 0 -> 4
[3] 0 -> 5
```

Comment: Thanks, you answer is so clear, both when you recreate the error and the proposal  solution.

You solved my problem.