# How to display RGL/CAR scatter3d plots as lines for trajectories

Tags: r, 3d, time-series, rgl, scatter3d

Undertaking a data visualization module, I'm trying to use R (course requirement) to visualize 3D trajectories of autonomous agents.
I have xyz data extracted from unity, looking to produce an interactive visualization.

With `scatterplot3D()` from the `plot3D` library I can use `type = "L"` and get a line connecting the points, but I loose the interactivity and "nice" looking car/rgl `scatterplot3d()`

similar to:
[Make a 3D rendered plot of time-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152987/make-a-3d-rendered-plot-of-time-series/8153463#8153463)
but with interactive, line connected dots!

this is the view I have... not enough rep for images yet :(

```r
scatter3D(fiveBoids.x, fiveBoids.y, fiveBoids.z, type = "L")
```

Is there anything like `type = "L"` in the rgl/car `scatterplot3d()` function? Is there a more suitable library I should be using?

Comment: Just Found Plotly!

Comment: `plot3Drgl` is similar to `plot3D`, but interactive.  `rgl` itself has lower level functions for more complicated interactivity in browser displays; see the WebGL vignette.

Comment: Have you tried `lines3d` in rgl ?